# Why knurling is a problem for boolean difference tool

Tags: modifiers

I want to cut the cylinder with the "Boolean-Difference" but it doesn't work. Someone could help me? Thank you :)[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your object: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: When using Boolean modifier you always need to specify which object should be used as a "cutter", i.e the one which your main object is interacting with. There is a special field for that in the Boolean modifier settings which is empty in your screenshot. So Boolean is actually doing nothing at the moment. Did you try to pick an object? While Boolean can and often has problems with complex geometry, there's some setup to be done first. Also please don't use all caps in the posts or title.

Comment: there is something wrong with your topology, probably faces or vertices overlapping, etc, I think it prevents the boolean

Comment: Please don't use all caps. Read: [why all caps is usually a bad idea](https://danieltitus.com/blog/advertising/237-why-all-caps-is-usually-a-bad-idea)